# Can a subclass have less parameters than its subclass?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, subclass, superclass

I'm currently tasked with editing code for an asteroid game in java. The main class is finished, but I have to complete the classes for the objects interacting in the game controlled by main. In the API for the game, the constructor for the superclass SpaceObject is written:

```
public SpaceObject(double xPos, double yPos, double xVel, double yVel, double radius){
    setXPosition(xPos);
    setYPosition(yPos);
    setXVelocity(xVel);
    setYVelocity(yVel);
    setRadius(radius);
}
```

And its subclass Comet is outlined as:

```
Comet(double xPos, double yPos, double xVel, double yVel, double radius){
  super(xPos, yPos, xVel, yVel, radius);
}
```

And finally, the issue, subclass LargeComet is outlined as:

```
LargeComet(double xPos, double yPos, double xVel, double yVel){
  super(xPos, yPos, xVel, yVel);
}
```

And LargeComet should have a radius of 40 (the static variable for this int is in the superclass SpaceObject).

I seem to be getting an error however that the parameters do not match. I can't have 5 parameter values in the constructor of the subclass LargeComet because then I get an error in the main class referring to it with 4 parameters (and I'm not supposed to change the main classes code there). Am I forgetting something here about explicitly calling a superclass constructor?

Comment: Try `super(xPos, yPos, xVel, yVel, 40);`.

Comment: Good lord it worked T_T Thank you! And the comments below make it clear to me why. I'm new to this java thing. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

You need to call super() with the arguments it expects(5 of them).  If one is static, you give it the static value instead of your arguments.  For a class whose parent takes 3 arguments, it would look something like this.

```
MyClass(int arg1, int arg2)
{
  super(arg1,arg2,5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since SpaceObject knows about a LargeComet radius already anyway, I would just call the Comet constructor with the 4 parameters passed into the LargeComet constructor, plus the constant from the superclass.  You aren't creating any more dependencies than are there already.